# Adding too much markers cause map lagging

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I currently developing an app using windows form with GMap.NET.

I'm currently facing an issue, when I add 500 markers on the map, my map getting laggy. I tried to drag the map and the respond is so slow.

Anyone have an explanation what cause this? Is this something related to PC specs? Can someone provide me some solution or suggestion?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: what marker type that you used... is it image markers or font markers? i think you are using an  image marker according to your situation that loading 500 image marker that takes a lot of memory specially if you have low memory

Comment: I'm using 'GMarkerGoogle' marker from GreatMaps.NET. And after some code changing, I manage to make it smooth when trying to load/add 500 markers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the PC specs because I got the same problem with only 150 markers.
Try dividing them by groups (100 markers per group) and display them on the map when the checkbox for each group is checked.